# how to extract a portion of a field and store it into another field in logstash filter?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, kibana-4

I have syslog files. I am using logstash syslog plugin filter to process those logs. I am getting messages in the `syslog_message` field like this one:

```
syslog_message:[cdp/interface.ERR] - {- -} Error writing CDP frame on system. Link is down
```

But I want a new field which should contain only the portion before .ERR i.e "cdp/interface". This portion varies and I dont know how many types will occur.
So I want a new field and want to store that portion on to that field, so that I can plot count of those terms in kibana.

current logstash configuration:

```
filter {
  if [type] == "syslog" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{DATA:syslog_program}(?:\[%{POSINT:syslog_pid}\])?: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" }
      add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
      add_field => [ "received_from", "%{host}" ]

    }
    date {
      target => "syslog_timestamp"
      match => [ "syslog_timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
    }
```

After adding a new grok to configuration file as suggested by @Val

```
grok {
  match => { "syslog_message" => "\[%{PROG:syslog_type}\.%{LOGLEVEL:syslog_level}\] %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" }
}
```

For some of the inputs grokparsefailure happens.
Some lines for which it fails are :

```
syslog_message: [hald.INFO]: Support query handler called
syslog_message:[mgmtd.INFO]: Finished database commit
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: How does your current Logstash config look like?

Comment: i edited with current logstash configuration  @Val

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either add one more pattern in your main `grok` filter or add another `grok` filter just for the `syslog_message` field

```
filter {
  if [type] == "syslog" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{DATA:syslog_program}(?:\[%{POSINT:syslog_pid}\])?: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" }
      add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
      add_field => [ "received_from", "%{host}" ]

    }
    # ====> add this <====
    grok {
      match => { "syslog_message" => "\[%{PROG:syslog_type}\.%{LOGLEVEL:syslog_level}\]:? %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" }

    }
    date {
      target => "syslog_timestamp"
      match => [ "syslog_timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
    }
```

As a result, you'd get two additional fields, namely:

- `syslog_type: cdp/interface`
- `syslog_level: ERR`

and `syslog_message` would only contain this `- {- -} Error writing CDP frame on system. Link is down`

Comment: hey , thanks for quick help but i am getting grokparsefailure for many inputs e.g syslog_message:[hald.INFO]: Support query handler called                             for such input logs i am getting grokparsefailure . @Val

Comment: Please update your question with a few log lines that fail.

Comment: i edited with 2 input logs for which it fails @Val .can u please look into it ?

Comment: I've modified my answer please take a look

Comment: hey Thanks a lot for your quickhelp @Val